# How to make jQuery UI's style not overwrite jqGrid's style?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is my situation, I'm having a jquery ui dialog with a jqgrid inside of it. When I opened the dialog, I can see that the grid's style has been overwritten by the dialog's style.

Is it possible to make the content of a dialog uncontaminated by the dialog's style?

I'm very sorry if the question has been asked before. Please do give me links to the threads if you be so kind.

I have made a jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/TGGKh/

Please any response would be appreciated

PS. Oh yes iframes does come to mind to overcome the style overwriting, but I dismissed the idea

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/TGGKh/

Please any response would be appreciated

Comment: What are the style that is being override because i can't determine where is the error ?!

Comment: Compare it with this http://jsfiddle.net/MUTRr/

Comment: @samir adel: please compare with the second url i gave :D thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line "`.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }`" from jquery-ui.css file.

Comment: I'd go with your suggestion, thank you samir. I think jquery ui should think interoperability with jqgrid since both are the most popular jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

Before you create more complex solution probably this simple CSS

```
html, body { font-size: 75%; }
```

will be already the workaround. The problem is that jqGrid CSS use `em` (relative font size) and jqGrid use absolute values in pixel. To use the same font size on the whole page you can use above CSS.