# Wrong font size when using jqGrid inside jQueryUI tab

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which works fine when displayed on a page on its own.

If I try to display the same grid inside jQueryUI tab, it still works fine – except that font size is wrong. What is happening is this:

When everything is working on a standalone page, the font size is picked up as follows:

```
Inherited from div#gbox_datatable.ui-jqgrid.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all, in file ui.jqgrid.css line 2
.ui-jqgrid{
    font-size:11px;
}
```

When the grid is placed inside a jQueryUI tab, howerver, it is overridden by a higher priority CSS command as follows:

```
Inherited from div#gbox_datatable.ui-jqgrid.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all, in file jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css line 60
.ui-widget .ui-widget{
    font-size:1em;
}
```

In other words, the fact that I have a ui-widget inside another ui-widget is overriding the desired font specifier.

How can I avoid this overriding?

I found same question at [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-font-size-when-using-a-grid-inside-a-jqueryui-tab/) without any answers.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ui.jqgrid.css` has the following definition

```
.ui-jqgrid {position: relative; font-size:11px;}
```

So if you add class "ui-jqgrid" to the div which holds the tabs the problem will be solved:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-jqgrid">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#results">Results</a></li>
        <li><a href="#log">Software</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="results" class="tabcontain"></div>
    <div id="log" class="tabcontain">
        <table id="grid"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
        <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the example above div with two tabs will be used: one with some general information and another with the the id="grid".

One more simple way will be just set

```
html, body { font-size: 75%; }
```

which set will reduce default font size of the page (1em) to the same which jqGrid uses (11px).

See one more way in [the resent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266992/how-to-make-jquery-uis-style-not-overwrite-jqgrids-style).

Comment: @isntn: You are welcome! It's interesting for me: which from described ways you choose?

Comment: I used <div id="tabs" class="ui-jqgrid">. My tabs div is going to hold only grids in tabs so adding class won't affect anything else.

Comment: I found that I had to set `table { font-size: 1em; }` to fix this.  Not sure exactly why that is... this is with floated divs in IE6 and Firefox 3.6 though.